# cmd batch job create directory not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I use cmd to create some folder, but not working , I am not sure something wrong.

here is the code:

```
rem @echo off
@cls

Set scriptsFolder=D:\Test\Scripts
Set SourceCodeFolder=D:\Test\SourceCode
Set DataFolder=D:\Test\Data

if not exist %scriptsFolder%
(
    mkdir %scriptsFolder%
)

if not exist %SourceCodeFolder%
(   
    mkdir %SourceCodeFolder%
)

if not exist %DataFolder%
(
    mkdir %DataFolder%
)


the error is syntax error after  Set DataFolder=D:\Test\Data:
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: "*but not working*" is not a valid Windows error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a multiline `If` statement open parenthesis <kbd>(</kbd> must stay on the same line where `If` is.

This syntax is invalid:

```
if not exist %scriptsFolder%
(
    mkdir %scriptsFolder%
)
```

This one is correct:

```
if not exist %scriptsFolder% (
    mkdir %scriptsFolder%
)
```

Also note that if you have a single instruction you can put everything on a single line:

```
if not exist %scriptsFolder% mkdir %scriptsFolder%
```

As last step of *refactoring* note that you may also always call `mkdir` and redirect `stderr` to `nul`, if directory exists it'll simply fail and it'll create it if it doesn't:

```
mkdir %scriptsFolder% 2> nul
```